# Data Sructures Project: File Explorer Tips

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, filesystems, explorer

## Context:

Hi guys! I need to do my final project for the DS course, and I was thinking about doing a File Explorer, with basic operations like **Searching, creating Folder or files, deleting them.** The point is to really make use of DS and algorithms, so I was thnking to use maybe a **B-tree, Linked-list or I know that I could use Bit vector** but I would like to implement it using trees, also I was thinking maybe a trie to do the search of the files, and do some sorting to search them by Name, creation date or something like.

### Question:

What I was wondering is like, what would be a nice OOP way for the system design, like have one class to all the algorithms? Another one for the tree? Another one for the files? If anybody could help me just to have like a nice roadmap to follow that would be great!

PS: I would be ding this in Java, I'm currently in my second year of CS.